# Removing `%` symbols in pandas column with replace() or rstrip() deletes values without `%` symbol too

Tags: python, pandas, replace, symbols, strip

I have a weird problem

I have a column `Value`, where I have values with and without `%`.

```
1  20%
2  30%
3  2.5
4  113
```

If I apply

```
data['Value'] = data['Value'].str.replace('%', '')
```

or

```
data['Value'] = data['Value'].str.rstrip('%')
```

it also deletes all values, which did not have `%` but keeps numbers for values, which had `%`.

As a result, I have

```
1  20
2  30
3  
4
```

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: Can't replicate. When the `Value` column are strings, it works fine using `replace`

Comment: Possibly the problem is due to mixed dtypes, Can you please check `df['value'].astype(str).str.rstrip('%')`?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'Value' : ['20%', '30%', 3.5, 113]})['Value'].str.replace('%', '')` replicates teh issue for me, so defo mixed data types nice catch @ShubhamSharma

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, great, that was my thought, but you got it right, appreciate it! Using your commands clears everything well but also converts empty to `nan`, which is not that a big problem. Thanks all!